# How can I hide a value in a widget in Python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to Python, I am from Android background. Like in Android we can set a value to any widget (that value is not visible) like,

```
textView.setTag(value)
textView.getTag()
```

Similarly, is there anything in Python tkinter?

Comment: What is the difference for you between hiding a value in a text widget and deleting it?

Answer (score 1):

You can set an attribute directly on the widget, and "hide" it there, that should not have adverse consequences:

```
widget = tk.Frame(root, ...)
widget._my_hidden_value = 42
```

There is the caveat that nothing is ever really hidden in python... And the question: "why would you need to do that?"